# Selecting Ids in from source list by other comparing another property against different list

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, generic-list

I have two `List`s of item classes objects such as;

SourceList

```
Id  DateTime
1   21.05.2019 10:00:00
2   21.05.2019 10:10:00
3   21.05.2019 10:20:00
4   21.05.2019 10:30:00
5   21.05.2019 10:40:00
6   21.05.2019 10:50:00
7   21.05.2019 11:00:00
```

DestinationList

```
Id  DateTime
1   21.05.2019 9:00:00
3   21.05.2019 10:25:00
5   21.05.2019 10:45:00
7   21.05.2019 10:30:00
9   21.05.2019 10:40:00
11  21.05.2019 10:50:00
```

I would select `Id`s from `SourceList` to find both:

- a. `Id`s which are exists on `SourceList` but not exists `DestinationList` (let alone this one is easy by itself)
- b. `Id`s which exists on both lists but retrieve only whose datetime bigger on `SourceList`

So the example result would be union of;

```
a. 2,4,6
b. 1,7

2,4,6,1,7
```

What is the most effective way have this result using lambda expressions.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var source = new[]
            {
                new Entry { Id = 1, DateTime = DateTime.Parse("21.05.2019 10:00:00") },
                new Entry { Id = 2, DateTime = DateTime.Parse("21.05.2019 10:10:00") },
                new Entry { Id = 3, DateTime = DateTime.Parse("21.05.2019 10:20:00") },
                new Entry { Id = 4, DateTime = DateTime.Parse("21.05.2019 10:30:00") },
                new Entry { Id = 5, DateTime = DateTime.Parse("21.05.2019 10:40:00") },
                new Entry { Id = 6, DateTime = DateTime.Parse("21.05.2019 10:50:00") },
                new Entry { Id = 7, DateTime = DateTime.Parse("21.05.2019 11:00:00") }
            };

            var destination = new[]
            {
                new Entry { Id = 1, DateTime = DateTime.Parse("21.05.2019 09:00:00") },
                new Entry { Id = 3, DateTime = DateTime.Parse("21.05.2019 10:25:00") },
                new Entry { Id = 5, DateTime = DateTime.Parse("21.05.2019 10:45:00") },
                new Entry { Id = 7, DateTime = DateTime.Parse("21.05.2019 10:30:00") },
                new Entry { Id = 9, DateTime = DateTime.Parse("21.05.2019 10:40:00") },
                new Entry { Id = 11, DateTime = DateTime.Parse("21.05.2019 10:50:00") }
            };

            var comparer = new EntryComparer();
            var partA = source.Except(destination, comparer);
            var partB = source.Intersect(destination, comparer)
                              .Where(i => source.First(j => j.Id == i.Id).DateTime >
                                          destination.First(j => j.Id == i.Id).DateTime);
            var result = partA.Concat(partB);
            foreach (var i in result)
                Console.WriteLine(i);
        }

        private class Entry
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

            public override string ToString() => $"{Id} {DateTime}";
        }

        private class EntryComparer : IEqualityComparer<Entry>
        {
            public bool Equals(Entry x, Entry y) => x.Id.Equals(y.Id);

            public int GetHashCode(Entry obj) => obj.Id.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2 21.05.2019 10:10:00
4 21.05.2019 10:30:00
6 21.05.2019 10:50:00
1 21.05.2019 10:00:00
7 21.05.2019 11:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways. One is to write your own `EqualityComparator` and list the result using `Except` and `Intersect` as shown by @Alex in the above result which is **solid code and reusable as well**, however if you are looking for quick results you can use the following using `where` and `any` and or the combinations of both.

So to obtain the results the linq queries would be as as follows

```
a) var resultWhereIdsExistsInSourceListButNotOnDestination = sourceList
.Where(l1 => !destinationList.Any(l2 => l2.Id == l1.Id))
.Select(l => l.Id);

b) var resultWhereIdsExistInBothWithDateGreaterInSourceList =
 sourceList
.Where(l1 => destinationList.Any(l2 => l2.Id == l1.Id && l1.Date > l2.Date))
.Select(l => l.Id);

c) var combinedResult = resultWhereIdsExistsInSourceListButNotOnDestination
   .Union(resultWhereIdsExistInBothWithDateGreaterInSourceList);
```

**Fiddle link** : https://dotnetfiddle.net/AGwFlC#

Note: I have used my own sample data. Also just to use the `ForEach` for readbility i have used `.ToList()` for demonstration purpose. One does not need to convert the enumerable to a list every time. Purely for demo purposes

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;

        public class Program
        {
            public static void Main()
            {
                var sourceList = new List<Foo>()
                {new Foo()
                {Id = 1, Date = DateTime.Now}, new Foo()
                {Id = 2, Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5)}, new Foo()
                {Id = 3, Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3)}, new Foo()
                {Id = 4, Date = DateTime.Now}, new Foo()
                {Id = 5, Date = DateTime.Now}};
                var destinationList = new List<Foo>()
                {new Foo()
                {Id = 2, Date = DateTime.Now}, new Foo()
                {Id = 3, Date = DateTime.Now}, new Foo()
                {Id = 4, Date = DateTime.Now}, new Foo()
                };

                Console.WriteLine("--IDs IN SOURCE LIST BUT NOT IN DESTINATION--------");
                var resultWhereIdsExistsInSourceListButNotOnDestination = 
sourceList
.Where(l1 => !destinationList.Any(l2 => l2.Id == l1.Id)).Select(l => l.Id).ToList();
                resultWhereIdsExistsInSourceListButNotOnDestination.ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine(r));
                Console.WriteLine("--IDs IN BOTH WHERE THE DATE IN SOURCE LIST IS GREATER--------");
                var resultWhereIdsExistInBothWithDateGreaterInSourceList = sourceList
    .Where(l1 => destinationList.Any(l2 => l2.Id == l1.Id && l1.Date > l2.Date)).Select(l => l.Id).ToList();
                resultWhereIdsExistInBothWithDateGreaterInSourceList.ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine(r));

                Console.WriteLine("------------------ UNINON-------------------------------------");
                resultWhereIdsExistsInSourceListButNotOnDestination
    .Union(resultWhereIdsExistInBothWithDateGreaterInSourceList).ToList().ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine(r));


            }
        }

        public class Foo
        {
            public DateTime Date
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public int Id
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }

        ;
```